# Xcode code sign failed and can't launch iOS program on real device

Tags: code-signing

I am noticed that my ios developer certification has been revoked. when I log in the account of apple developer center. An Apple Developer Agreement pop out. I agree and click 'submit' button. But a error occur:

```
We are unable to process your request.An unknown error occurred.
```

I get stuck here. I can not launch iOS program on my iphone device. In Xcode 7.3, I get Preferences->Accounts. I have added my apple ID. But it did not display any team/oraginization that i joined. It always showed 'loading...'

If I ignored and tried to run iOS program on my device. I get this error:

```
Code Sign error: No code signing identities found: No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) were found.
```

Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Comment: try agreeing to the Apple agreement in a different browser.

Comment: I have tried both on safari and chrome. Nothing different.